# format mysite user profile property

Tags: 2010, my-site

does anybody know how i can format a user property value in a mysite.  I need to re - format the employees work telephone number that is fed from AD via UPA.  Ive edited the xslt of the people search and that works fine but now i need to update the employees mysite as well.  Ive looked in the person and personcontext aspx's and can see the ProfilePropertyValue tags but im not sure the best way to go about reformtting them.